# How to read and convert TSV file into NPZ with base64

Tags: python, numpy, csv, base64, npz-file

I have TSV file with headers and some values. I want to read it and convert it into base 64 and later to NPZ format. I have a code as follows:

```
import base64
import numpy as np
import csv
import sys
import zlib
import time
import mmap

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
   
FIELDNAMES = ['image_id', 'image_w','image_h','num_boxes', 'boxes', 'features']
infile = '/content/drive/MyDrive/test2015_resnet101_faster_rcnn_genome.tsv.0'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    in_data = {}
    with open(infile, "r+b") as tsv_in_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(tsv_in_file, delimiter='\t', fieldnames = FIELDNAMES)
        for item in reader:
            for field in ['features']:
                item[field] = np.frombuffer(base64.decodestring(item[field]), 
                      dtype=np.float32).reshape((int(item['num_boxes']),-1))
            in_data[item['image_id']] = item['features']
    print (in_data)
    np.savez('data.npz', in_data)
```

Running the code, I get this error:

> Error
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> 29             #print(item['image_id'])
> 30             for field in ['boxes', 'features']:
> ---> 31                 item[field] = np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(item[field]), dtype=np.float32).reshape((int(item['num_boxes']),-1))
> 32                # print(item[field][0:1])
> 33             in_data[item['image_id']] = item
>
> /usr/lib/python3.7/base64.py in b64decode(s, altchars, validate)
> 85     if validate and not re.fullmatch(b'[A-Za-z0-9+/]*={0,2}', s):
> 86         raise binascii.Error('Non-base64 digit found')
> ---> 87     return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
> 88
> 89
>
> Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (360285) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

I assume it conflicts with **FIELDNAMES**

Any idea how to resolve this?

The TSV File that I have:

[TSV_FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzn78.jpg)

Column A has `image_id` followed by other field names.

The result that I am expecting

[NPZ_FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJrcQ.png)

where the red boundary represents the `image_id` and rest of the values are 'features'

Comment: can you edit your question to include the full trace back?

Comment: @DrBwts I just did

Comment: `base64` encodings use 4 characters to encode 3 bytes & will pad out the data so you always get exact multiples of 4 characters. It looks like the original encoding of your `TSV` file isn't `base64` as at least one of the strings you are reading in has a length that isn't divisible by 4.  As a result trying to decode as `base64` is failing.

Comment: @DrBwts can I remove/skip that encoding that is causing issue?

Comment: I could be wrong but looking at your `TSV` pic some of the entries are `int` & some are possibly `base64` encoded strings. You need to be clear which is which when reading in your data. Not knowing how your data was generated or saved initially I cant say more than that. Is it possible to supply some typical sample data?